# How to install StackApplet on Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome, python, dpkg

I would love to install [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-5-beta-2-r) on Debian 6.0.2!

I downloaded 'stackapplet_1.4.0_all.deb' and ran following command:

```
root@debian:/home/dagrevis/Downloads# dpkg -i stackapplet_1.4.0_all.deb 
Selecting previously deselected package stackapplet.
(Reading database ... 132125 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking stackapplet (from stackapplet_1.4.0_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of stackapplet:
 stackapplet depends on python-appindicator; however:
  Package python-appindicator is not installed.
dpkg: error processing stackapplet (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 stackapplet
```

I guess that I don't have 'python-appindicator'. I searched for it, but, unfortunately, I couldn't find it.

P.S. I am using Gnome and that shouldn't be a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now extremely easy to install StackApplet on Debian thanks to a fallback module for AppIndicators that I wrote, which ships with StackApplet. You can install it by downloading the source package for the latest version from [its Launchpad page.](https://launchpad.net/~stackapplet-dev/+archive/stackapplet)

From there, you simply need to extract the contents of the archive and run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

...which will take care of installation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the quick answer is that the .deb package you're trying to install is designed for Ubuntu, not Debian. Ubuntu has a "python-appindicator" package and Debian doesn't.

You could try just unpacking the "generic archive" at https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-5-beta-2-r and seeing whether it works. I note that the code has "/usr/share/" hardcoded all over the place, so you'll have to unpack it to your root directory. Eugh. Maybe try using Checkinstall or the like?

Comment: The newest version available from the download site comes with a `distutils` installer so there is no need to 'unpack' it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

StackApplet depends on [indicator-application](https://launchpad.net/indicator-application). This is a Canonical project which is packaged for Ubuntu but not for Debian yet.

There is a [proposal to package indicator-application for Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609503), and the [Ayatana project](http://wiki.debian.org/Ayatana/Packages) is working on it, but the package fails to build for the moment.

In the meantime, you can try one of the following approaches:

- Grab the dependencies from Ubuntu as binary packages: [`libappindicator0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libappindicator0) and [`python-appindicator`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python-appindicator).
- Grab the [source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/lucid/indicator-application) and try to recompile, hoping that you'll be able to fix whatever problem Ayatana encountered.
- Grab the StackApplet source and compile without the parts that require indicator-application (the applet description reads “any Linux PC running Gnome **or** supporting AppIndicators”).

Comment: It is more than possible to run StackApplet without the AppIndicator package installed thanks to the fallback module I wrote. Please see my answer.